# Как в java быстрее всего поднять все символы в строке вверх по алфавиту?

Tags: java, алгоритм, строки, char

То есть, например, "bac" превратить в "mln".
Посимвольно проходить по строке и добавлять нужное число (индекс сдвига) к каждому символу получается долговато (строк может быть много и они могут быть довольно длинными).
Может есть другие идеи?

Comment: `Посимвольно проходить по строке и добавлять нужное число (индекс сдвига) к каждому символу получается долговато` почему долговато? Вам надо сдвинуть каждый символ - вы проходите и сдвигаете. Если долго из за неизменяемости строк- то пользуйтесь стринг билдером или что там в джаве представляет собой изменяемую строку.

Comment: А вам точно нужно изменят _каждый_ символ?  Или какой-то конкретный тип символов (любые буквы, английские буквы, цифры, знаки препинания)?  И что для вас значит "долго"?  Можно придумать короткий код с регуляркой, но работать он будет дольше, чем "долговатая" последовательная замена в `StringBuilder / StringBuffer`

Comment: Долго в том смысле, что мы проходим по каждому символу по отдельности. Думал, может кто знает способ как "поднять" сразу всю строку.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю вы хотите сделать шифратор.
Можете пройтись циклом по всей строке, и код каждой буквы изменить на 11.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //входные данные
        String string = "bac";
        int change = 11;

        //перевод
        StringBuilder copy = new StringBuilder();;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) copy.append((char) (string.charAt(i) + 11));

        //вывод
        System.out.println(copy);
    }
}
```

Выводит

```
mln
```

Comment: Просто думаю в таком случае не будет проблем с тайм-лимитами, фактически для компьютера 50.000 операций не проблема.

Comment: Вы знакомы с понятием вычислительной сложности? При такой реализации она получается квадратичной, т.е. для строки длиной 50000 операций будет миллиарды. Но StringBuilder выручит

Comment: Ну тогда заменить String copy на StringBuilder copy, и вместо += использовать .append().

Comment: ОК. В конце, наверное, стоит copy.toString() сделать

Comment: Да, этот способ я знаю. Думал, может можно как-то "увеличить" сразу всю строку.

Comment: Я не думаю что этот способ особо нагрузит вам процессор, разве-что если вы не захотите зашифровать посимвольно войну и мир.